# The difference between proper nouns and specified common nouns (eg 'my car')

Tags: grammar, nouns, pronouns

Proper nouns are supposed to denote a *specific* entity. Why aren't the phrases "my car", "her hat", "their dinner", etc., considered proper? They each refer to *specific* entities, but aren't usually considered proper.

Comment: A phrase is not a noun. Proper nouns are capitalised. They are a specific name for a person or a thing. The name identifies the person or thing.

Comment: @NigelJ But isn't "united kingdom" also more a phrase than a noun? Perhaps, somewhere in the backwaters of history there was a Lampukistan kingdom that could be described as united, but even if we talk about that *specific* geographic/historic entity as a "united kingdom", we nevertheless (at least today) use the phrase with proper noun capitalization only when talking about the (even more?) specific United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland - because that's a name and not a description

Comment: Offsetting (the first word of a sentence / line of verse) and a sign of respect / veneration  (John, Pope Pius XII, God) or both ('A Christmas Carol') are factors that should also be taken into account. And the existence of uncapitalisable proper nouns ('iPhones are the best selling smartphones').

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that the car, the hat and the dinner in your examples are specific only when the person or people referenced by the possessive pronouns are known. Not only that but when the pronouns reference other people the phrases reference other cars, hats and dinners.

For instance if *you* say "That is my car" then the phrase will refer to the car owned by Newman and we can replace "my" with "Newman's. If *I* say "That is my car" then the phrase will refer to the car owned by Ben and we can replace "my" with "Ben's". We also replace your new Mercedes with my old Nissan:-) Similarly if *I* say "That is your car" I am referring to the Mercedes but if *you* say "That is your car" (referring to me) you are referring to the Nissan.

The previous paragraph, of course, includes four examples of true proper nouns. These are the nouns with the first letter capitalised (Newman, Ben, Mercedes and Nissan). The point about these is that, although there are many people called Newman and Ben and also many cars made by Mercedes and Nissan the people are known by the names in many contexts and the brand names always refer to the same brand. That is you can't, truthfully, point to a Nissan and say it's a Mercedes but *I* can point to a Nissan and say "That's my car" whereas other people can point to other cars and say the same thing.

The point is that proper nouns refer directly to specific people, places organisations and sometimes animals and other things as well and only mean other people, places organisations and so on when two or more of them have the same name (me and Ben Fogle or Boston, Massachusetts and Boston, Lincolnshire for example) but phrases including a possessive pronoun and a noun mean different things depending on the person identified by the personal pronoun.

Comment: What about a mother or a wife saying "my Peter"?

Comment: @Peter That's a possessive noun phrase incorporating a proper noun. The noun doesn't stop being a proper noun because it's associated with a possessive. The OP wasn't asking about that, he was asking why a phrase combining a possessive and a common noun isn't considered a proper noun.

Comment: @BoldBen So which of the following would be grammatically correct: "Newman's car" or "Newman's Car"? Is it the former as I could have multiple cars?

Comment: Unless they appear at the start of sentences nouns are only capitalised in English if they are proper nouns. It is possible for 'Car' or 'Newman's Car' to be proper nouns but that is not the normal case. You might, for instance, give a dog you own the name 'Car' in which case the dog's name would be a proper noun and the dog could be called 'Newman's Car', you might even give one of your cars the nickname 'Car' in which case it would be a proper noun but that would be uncommon and rather odd. However 'Nissan' in "Ben's Nissan" would be a proper noun because it's a brand name.

Answer (score 1):

A proper noun has a name, and the name is capitalised when referring to that thing (or person) by its name.

A common noun is not a name, and a capital letter is not used.

Thus "my car" refers to a particular car, yes, but not by its name. You might have a VW Beetle and refer to "my Herbie" because Herbie is the name [proper, capitalised] of the car [common, uncapitalised]. The same applies to "my Peter" instead of "my husband" — the wife is referring to a particular person in both cases, but common nouns aren't capitalised.

Side note: in English up to around 1750, and still in some other languages, it was indeed usual to capitalise **all** nouns; proper nouns were distinguished by setting the whole word in italics or as all-capitals. But that's not modern custom and usage.

Comment: About “A proper noun *has* a name” (emphasis, mine), I’d go further and say that proper nouns *are* names.

Answer (score 0):

> Proper nouns are supposed to denote a specific entity.

This is incorrect as it is too much of a generalisation. Capitalisation does not change a noun into a proper noun. It is the proper noun that enables the use of capitals.

Compare the following:

"There is a Walmart two miles down the road."; (There must be hundreds of Walmarts.)

"How many Johns do we have in this class?"; (We are not talking about any specific "John".)

"I spoke to Her Majesty, Queen Elizabeth." but "The queens met at the castle." (Note the capitalisation of "Her" and "Majesty".)

"The United Kingdom left the EU" with "Ruritania was a group of small states ruled by various prices and earls that became a **united kingdom** under Charles the First."

"She told me that God had caused the earthquake and that **H**e had done it because the people had been bad."

And let's not forget the initial letter of a sentence and of a line of poetry, or the use of capitalisation in philosophy to indicate the essential attribute of something.

Etc.